mesh object has no attribute calc normals split
I just started using the application. I applied texture to my 3D model. I am currently trying to save as fbx but most of the textures are not saved as fbx. I also tried the solutions on the internet (I made a copy and checked the box next to it. It still didn't work). Now I am trying with Better Fbx Exporter and I am getting this error. Can you help me please? 

This function has been removed in Blender V4.1 and changed (I think) to https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_add. You can either go back to Blender 4.0 or ask the addon maintainer to update its code. Or do it yourself if you feel like you can. Cheers

I'm back to version 4.0. It didn't work again. How do I save it as fbx without breaking the texture of my model?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures
